# Ajustar timezone en cada consulta desde Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

He desarrollado un portal para un cliente y, a última hora me ha pedido ajustar todas las fechas y horas para horarios extranjeros.

¿Existe alguna forma de que MySQL me proporcione la fecha traducida a otro Timezone desde Laravel?

Conozco la funcion [convert_tz](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)), lo que busco es un sistema mucho más automatizado en el cual no tenga que modificar todo mi código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar los date mutators que propociona laravel 5.2

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Cuando una columna es considerada fecha en el modelo es parseada automaticamente a una instancia de Carbon, con esta instancia ya puedes formatear la fecha al formato que tu quieras.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['user_date'];
}
```

Por defecto el formato de fecha es este ***'Y-m-d H:i:s'***

Aunque puedes cambiarlo directamente con el atributo de la clase modelo

```
protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y H:i:s';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no conocía la existencia de Carbon. Ahora mismo me pongo a revisarlo enteramente para usarlo en el proyecto!

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal Si das el visto bueno a alguien, dale también un voto, es lo normal.

Comment: Ya se lo he dado, pero como tengo poca repu no se muestra mi voto.